# Is there a function in Vertica is equivalent to DATENAME in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

In sql i will get DateName from the following query

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,'10/24/2013') as theDayName
```

to return 'Thursday'

have any equivalent function in Vertica?

Comment: Which DBMS has `datename` (`SQL` is **not** the name of a DBMS product - it's a query langauge). And what does it do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i mean MS SQL server

Comment: You need to tell us what `datename` does (and in which DBMS). People usually don't know all functions of all DBMS in the world. So again: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: For these types of questions, if you look up what the PostgreSQL function is 99 times out of 100 it will be the Vertica function as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way without using a custom UDF is using [`TO_CHAR`](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TO_CHAR.htm) formatting:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2014-08-21 14:34:06', 'DAY');
```

This returns the full uppercase day name. `Day` gives the mixed-case day name, and `day` gives the lowercase day name.

You can find more template patterns [here](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TemplatePatternsForDateTimeFormatting.htm).

Comment: using getdate() how can i write the above query . SELECT TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP getdate(), 'DAY');
getting error

Comment: Okay, in your question you passed an actual date, not a `GETDATE()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing a custom UDF ([`weekday_name`](https://github.com/sKwa/vertica/blob/master/UDFSQL/sql_funcs.sql)). Once installed, you can use:

```
SELECT weekday_name(dayofweek(TO_DATE('10/24/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')))
```

Comment: thanks for your support . But getting error as    Function weekday_name(int) does not exist, or permission is denied                                                                                                                                                              for weekday_name(int)
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to ad                                                                                                                                                             d explicit type casts

Comment: @Haris That's because you need to install the UDF.

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Use this script, it will produce the desired result  **in Vertica**

> SELECT DAYOFWEEK (TIMESTAMP '2014-08-21 05:26:24.000');

[Reference . .](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/DAYOFWEEK.htm)